# System.InvalidOperationException: Internal connection fatal error. Error state: 15, Token : 143

Tags: api, sql-server-2016, windows-server-2016, iis-10, always-encrypted

We have been getting this error frequently in application when an API call happens between application server and database server to fetch data.

While troubleshooting the issue restarted both application and database servers (using my account to logged into server) and there is no luck. Later we found that when logged into server using a Service Account which is used as Application Pool Identity for the site resolved the issue.

Note: this issue is not happening for all API calls. Only for the calls which  involve fetching encrypted data using SQL Server Always Encrypted method.

So, alternative days or whenever we noticed the issue we are logging into application server with the service account to resolve this issue.

We are using windows server 2016, IIS10.

Can anyone help us why this peculiar behavior is happening?

Thank you in advance

> System.InvalidOperationException: Internal connection fatal error. Error state: 15, Token : 143
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryCloseInternal(Boolean closeReader)
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.Close()
> at System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.Finally()   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.Dispose()
> at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the application pool to the users who can log in to SQL Server. When the application pool itself is added as a log-in user, no matter what its identity is, it can connect to the database.

Open database which you want application pool can login. Select Security-> Logins, right click and new login...
[image]

Login name is IIS APPPOOL\app pool name.
[image]

Check public and sysadmin in Server Roles.
[image]

Create a new login name NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM in the same way.

Comment: we have used service Account as Application Pool Identity not the default one.        we are using the similar Queries for all the methods...but this error occurs only when fetching the data from the tables which were encrypted using SQL Server Always Encrypted method with Windows certificate store- Current user 

when this issue occurred we try to close all the Active connections in SQl server and even restarted the server. issue fixed only when server was logged in with Service account